# Tensorflow and threading

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow

Below is the simple mnist tutorial (i.e. single layer softmax) from the Tensorflow website, which I tried to extend with a multi-threaded training step:

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import tensorflow as tf
import threading

# Training loop executed in each thread
def training_func():
  while True:
      batch = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
      global_step_val,_ = sess.run([global_step, train_step], feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})
      print("global step: %d" % global_step_val)
      if global_step_val >= 4000:
        break

# create session and graph
sess = tf.Session()

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
global_step = tf.Variable(0, name="global_step")
y = tf.matmul(x,W) + b

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y, y_))

inc = global_step.assign_add(1)
with tf.control_dependencies([inc]):
  train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

# initialize graph and create mnist loader
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)

# create workers and execute threads
workers = []
for _ in range(8):
  t = threading.Thread(target=training_func)
  t.start()
  workers.append(t)

for t in workers:
  t.join()

# evaluate accuracy of the model
print(accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels},
  session=sess))
```

I must be missing something, as 8 threads as below yield inconsistent results (accuracy approx. = 0.1), when with 1 thread only the expected accuracy is obtained (approx. 0.92). Does anybody have a clue about my mistake(s)? Thanks!

Comment: You do realize that TF graphs are compiled and executed by a heavily parallel engine. If you look at the CPU utilization during single thread training you will see all the cores receiving load, not just one. What do you want to accomplish by threading the training? I expect the problems you are seeing come from multiple threads updating weights without any control and overwriting each other's changes.

Comment: My objective would be to speedup costly training. I understand TF is genuinely parallel, but also that speedup can be obtained with multithreading - eg in the example above, range(1) yields 15-20% usage for all cores, whereas range(16) leads to 60-80% usage.

Comment: I suspected my problem comes from uncontrolled concurrent weight updates indeed. However [this TF tutorial code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.12/tensorflow/models/embedding/word2vec_optimized.py) does something analogous to my sample code (l.319 to l.340), but I don't get why this works in their case. Maybe their training op (word2vec.neg_train) manages these concurrent updates internally?

Answer (score 2):

Note that unfortunately, `threading`with python doesn't create real parallelism because of the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). So what happens here is that you will have multiple threads which are all running on the same CPU where in reality they are running sequentially. Therefore, I would suggest using Coordinator in Tensorflow. More information about Coordinator can be found here:

https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/threading_and_queues
https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data

Finally, I would suggest you say:

```
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    your code should go here... 'for the first thread'
```

Then use another cpu for the other thread and so on...
Hope this answer finds you well!!

Comment: Just saw the answer and didn't test it yet, but the information looks relevant, thanks for answering :) I upvote for now, and I'll select the answer if it solves the issue (when I have time to test :) )