# Thread-safe graph usage in Tensorflow

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow, flask, keras

I have a flask app that first of all loads a keras model and then executes the prediction function. According to [this answer](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6462#issuecomment-385962748) I save the tensorflow graph in a global variable and use the same graph for the prediction function.

```
def load_model():
    load_model_from_file()
    global graph
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()

def predict():
    with graph.as_default():
        tagger = Tagger(self.model, preprocessor=self.p)
        return tagger.analyze(words)

@app.route('/predict', methods=['GET'])
def load_and_predict():
    load_model()
    predict()
```

However, this leads to a problem whenever multiple requests are the send to the server. How can I make this code thread-safe, or to be more specific, how do I use tensorflow graphs correctly in a multi-threaded environment?

Comment: From the answer of this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41697662/tensorflow-and-threading, the threading with python is not a "real" parallelism. Moreover, when you do the inference, the weights of the network are *not* updated. So I think that it is pretty safe to use a global graph

Comment: Do you have an update on this after 2 years? - I am having the same problem and can't figure out the answer.

Comment: I only remember that I did find a solution to this using the concepts described in the two answers. Unfortunately I don't have access to the code anymore, so I can't tell you exactly what I did :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usually, you should use a session while working with threads in tensorflow.

```
intra_parallel_thread_tf = 1
inter_parallel_thread_tf = 1

session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=intra_parallel_thread_tf,
                          inter_op_parallelism_threads=inter_parallel_thread_tf)

tf.Session(graph=tf.get_default_graph(), config=session_conf)
GRAPH = tf.get_default_graph()
```

But this is pretty general. It also depends on the error you get.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it synchronized with a lock.

```
import threading    
lock = threading.Lock()

def load_and_predict():
     with lock:
        load_model()
        predict()
```

Comment: HI - I tried this but I have the problem that I need to load the model only once and do a bunch of predictions with it. Loading the model each time is not adequate (when there are many request for prediction).

Comment: That's true in that case you can still use a lock, but load the model once.